# pgAdmin server not showing up

Tags: pgadmin

Total n00b question here. I am using pgAdmin to attempt to administer a remote PostgreSQL server. I click the connect icon, fill out the form, click 'OK'. The form goes away and in the status bar it says:

> Connecting to database... Done.

The problem is, nothing else changes. My server doesn't come up under 'Server Groups' in the object browser, I get no server properties or statistics, or anything else. Yes, the server is running, yes, `pg_hba.conf` has been modified to allow my access, and yes, the username/password are right.

I was getting errors from pgAdmin before. I fixed all of those things, now I get nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the program and/or your computer?

I had the same issue where I was trying to add a connection but nothing was showing up after trying a few times.  I closed it and opened it up again and I had 4 of the same connections!

Comment: It's always the stupidest solution, thanks.

Comment: This definitely was the right answer - I had the exact same problem.

Comment: I wonder they still haven't fixed it. The same problem and same solution.

Comment: Still a problem with pgadmin3.