# paAdmin4 not showing at all in browser. no server,, no..nothing

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I started pgadmin to see my database today, but nothing shows up in the browser section on the left. I don't know what to do with it.

It was working fine until last night.

[image: pgAdmin not showing]

[image: pgAdmin dashboard not showing]

Comment: You need to restart a connection, they are not persistent.

Comment: `Dashboard->Configure pgAdmin->Browser->Nodes` - do you have there everything set to show?

Comment: please see my image above "pgAdmin not showing" @Łukasz Kamiński

Comment: I already saw image but it doesn't answer my question. You would need to switch to Dashboard tab and then follow path I have written.

Comment: nothing in the dashboard so i cannot even reach "Configure pgAdmin"

Comment: i even reinstalled pgadmin...

Comment: I think you have similar issue to someone I answered today and what worked for that person is to switch from pgAdmin4 to pgAdmin3, with IMO has much better UX than its most recent iteration. You could either download it from official archive or grab LTS version (still maintained and working with 9.6) from one of the official PostgreSQL redistributors: https://www.bigsql.org/pgadmin3/

Comment: Similar issue at me, my server disappears all the time. PgAdmin 3 was fine, don't know why they shifted to this ***

Answer (score 0):

I actually just dealt with this problem for the second time (conveniently far enough apart to have forgotten the answer in between) and I'm honestly surprised it's not more frequently asked. This may or may not resolve your issue; it did resolve an issue which has the same symptoms for me.

---

## Resolving the issue

1. reboot the machine (`reboot -h now` or pick your poison)
2. start/restart the database (`pg_ctl -D database_name start`)
3. remove the `pgadmin4.db`from the `DATA_DIR` specified in `config.py`

   - For example on OS X (El Capitan), `DATA_DIR` is at `/Users/username/.pgadmin/`
   - I moved it to a temporary location to save it just in case, if everything goes well you won't end up needing it
4. start pgAdmin 4
5. (re)create the server group and server based on the initialization prompts

   - this is based on whatever parameters you used to configure the database to begin with; for example, if your database is accessible only to a specific user, you'd need to set that in the server settings
6. give it a second to re-load, but you should be all set

---

## Why it works

The root of the problem is that when you do a reinstall (or another major reconfiguration), pgAdmin cannot handle (that's the super technical term) the fact that there's a conflicting copy of `pgadmin4.db`.

The documentation which leads me to this conclusion [in the manual](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/desktop_deployment.html) (somewhat understated in the original):

> In order to configure the Python code, follow these steps:
>
> **Ensure that any existing configuration database (pgadmin4.db) is moved out of the way** in the web/ directory containing the pgAdmin Python code.

which I am interpreting as meaning "if you're performing an update, you must remove the old `pgadmin4.db` database, otherwise you'll get a blank page."

---

## Related questions

I've only been able to find two additional questions which reference this problem.

- [pgAdmin server not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050422/pgadmin-server-not-showing-up)
- [pgAdmin III : No servers showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494384/pgadmin-iii-no-servers-showing-up?rq=1)

While I somewhat agree it's not technically a "programming" question, its solution involves understanding and modifying the operation of an open source project, and doesn't meet the criteria to be included in [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: `I moved it to a temporary location to save it just in case` this! Did it with plain `rm` and now it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I'll say, moving to pgAdmin4 version 3 (browser based) made my life a lot easier. I used to have this problem more often than not, and I don't anymore.